# Как настроить авторизацию на asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите наглядно, как настроить авторизацию на *asp.net mvc*.

Нужно всего лишь, чтобы определённый контроллер работал для *роли-1*.

В инете много нашёл, но там движок сам создаёт свои таблицы пользователей. А мне желательно иметь таблицу `Users`, где ещё пароль будет в незашифрованном виде, т.к. некоторые администраторы должны его видеть.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоватся ASP.Net Identity. Там все просто, создаете класс который наследует IdentityUser и определяете открытое свойство в котором будете хранить свой пароль.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Вы можете создать свой собственный Membership Provider и задать логику обработки. Пример смотреть [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers).

Вариант 2. Создать свой фильтр авторизации [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.3.php).

Вариант 3. Используйте новый способ [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

Comment: Membership уже давно obsolete, на смену ему пришел ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: @cpp_user Добавил третий вариант. Спасибо.